# fusionar select

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT vendedores.Nombre,(SELECT  SUM(factura.Total) FROM factura WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=factura.CodigoVendedor AND factura.Tipo='Factura'
AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre)+(SELECT  SUM(sales.Total) FROM sales WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=sales.CodigoVendedor 
AND sales.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre)+(SELECT SUM(abonos.Abono) FROM abonos,saldos WHERE 
abonos.NumFactura=saldos.NumFactura AND 
saldos.CodigoVendedor=vendedores.Codigo AND abonos.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09- 
13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY vendedores.Nombre)
FROM vendedores
```

Como hago para que en esa consulta el "between Fecha '' and ''" quede por fuera como de forma global por decirlo asi, despues de "from vendedores"

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe! No tengo muy claro que en esta consulta se pueda unificar ese BETWEEN, dado que es el mismo código, puede sonar posible, pero la forma de sacar los datos obliga a que ese between no pueda ser global , ya que hablamos de muchas tablas diferentes.

Answer (score 4):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow.

Me parece que este tipo de consultas quedan mejor expresadas y más claras cuando usas `JOIN` para unir las tablas.

En el `JOIN` vas agregando cada tabla (si es posible con un alias de una sola letra para no tener luego que usar el nombre completo de la tabla) y pones por fuera los criterios `WHERE`.

Ahora bien, lo que tú quieres en el planteamiento, me parece que no es posible. Si cada tabla tiene un campo relativo a la fecha, no puede haber manera de *globalizarlo* (al menos me parece que no, a no ser que otro experto me desmienta), porque cada columna fecha pertenece **a su tabla**.

Lo que sí sería interesante es preguntarse:

- **¿por qué en mi diseño se repite tanto esa columna `Fecha` en tres tablas si luego tengo que filtrar tres veces?**
- **¿no tendré que relacionar las tablas de otra manera, de modo que ese campo `Fecha` no se triplique innecesariamente?**

Yo propondría escribir la consulta así. Al menos es una consulta menos confusa, se ve quién se relaciona con quien, qué filtros se aplican y hasta nos podría dar una idea para re-diseñar el modelo de datos:

```
SELECT 
    v.Nombre,
    SUM(f.Total)+SUM(sales.Total)+SUM(a.Abono) total     
FROM vendedores v 
INNER JOIN
    factura f ON v.Codigo=f.CodigoVendedor
    sales     ON v.Codigo=sales.CodigoVendedor
    saldos    ON v.Codigo=saldos.CodigoVendedor
    abonos a  ON saldos.NumFactura=a.NumFactura
WHERE
    f.Tipo='Factura' 
    AND f.Fecha     BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14'   
    AND sales.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14'
    AND a.Fecha     BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14'
GROUP BY v.Nombre
```

Comment: Hola lo que me pasaste esta muy bien pero me dio un resultado diferente

Comment: Nombre
Total
rana rene2
230437.61
RAUL GONZALEZ
144020
eso me deberia dar

Comment: tu consulta me devuelve 
Nombre
total
rana rene2
15735021.890000004
RAUL GONZALEZ
973210

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez me parece muy extraño. ¿Podrías ejecutar cada consulta por separado, y sumar los tres valores?